# Not able to save the SDL Tridion component with Greek Content having 31 pages from MS word document

Tags: sites-9.1, component

We have Greek content in MS Word (31 Pages) formatted, while copy pasting the content from word document in to Tridion component RTF field and trying to **Save and Close**, it hangs up and throws an Error "Field 'Content' has invalid value", but when we tried with saving 5 page content in different components it saved the component. Please let me know what might be the issue

environment: SDL Tridion Sites 9.1

[image]

Comment: Instead of copying directly from Word, try pasting the content to Notepad (not Notepad++) and then copy and paste this to the RTF.

Comment: That will work, but the formatting will be lost.

Comment: you need to check the event viewer to see what is the exact exception. what was being parsed and tried to save. maybe some illegal char or tag

Comment: What other testing have you done? Did you try with the first 6, then 7, then 8 etc. pages to ascertain if (a) the size is the issue (b) a specific page has breaking content. Did you view the source tab and then back to the content (this will push the XSL against the XHTML and may remove or bring to light problematic content). In general, just pasting Word content into a RTF is not a good idea at all - you get tons of complex formatting syntax that makes editing later much more tricky.

Comment: Hi Mark Saunders, Thanks for your reply. I tried with all the options you mentioned still I am getting the same error, I have a question here, like what is the capacity of the RTF field we can add the content to it? or is there way to remove unnecessary tags being  generated.

Answer (score 2):

I remember seeing something similar waaaay back in Tridion 2009.
There the solution was to increase the height of the RTF field. I kid you not :). It's worth a shot.

Comment: Hi Atila, I tried increasing the height of the RTF field, but it didn't work.